# Change jdk path in IntelliJ 13 when compiling from 32 bit program file folder to 64 bit one

Tags: java, compiler-construction, intellij-idea, 32bit-64bit

I'm getting this issue when trying to Make my java project.  I just uninstalled my 64 bit jdk for various reasons and installed the 32 bit one.  I'm getting the error:

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java" (in
>   directory "C:\Users\$username.IntelliJIdea13\system\compile-server"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

How do I get the compiler to use the jdk in the C:\Program Files (x86) folder which I now have?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the menu: `File` -> `Project Structure...`.

On the left, below "Platform Settings", you have "SDKs": click on it; you can add your new JDK here.

Always in the same window, below "Project Settings", select "Project": you have the option to select the JDK which you just added.

Comment: I never would have looked under `Project Structure`. Way to go, IntelliJ