# Intellij error=2 No such file or directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

Installed intellij and added sdk path to project structure, but when i try to run i get:

```
Error: Cannot run program "/home/$USER/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java" 
(in directory"/home/$USER/.intelliJIdea2016.3/system/compile-server"):
error=2, No such file or directory
```

Both files (/home/$USER/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java and /home/$USER/.intelliJIdea2016.3/system/compile-server) exists.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: What OS do you use? Are you sure it's the full JDK installation path and not a JRE?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am using ubuntu 16.10 and i downloaded the JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html, the path is to the extracted folder

Comment: Please specify what OS do you use. As of now, question is unclear.

Comment: Do you see `$USER` in the error message or did you replace it when posting the question?

Comment: @CrazyCoder $USER is my replacement of my username

Comment: Can you run Java manually, e.g. `/home/$USER/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -version`?

Comment: Sorry for long response time, what eventually worked was installing the openjdk using apt-get and setting it in intellij. Dont know why it didnt work with http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.

Comment: This actually happens in OSX as well, but the fix was reapplying SDK settings for the entire project

Answer (score 36):

The answer from here [Change jdk path in IntelliJ 13 when compiling from 32 bit program file folder to 64 bit one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392110/change-jdk-path-in-intellij-13-when-compiling-from-32-bit-program-file-folder-to/22392702#22392702) worked for me

From the menu: `File` -> `Project Structure...`.

On the left, below "Platform Settings", you have "SDKs": click on it; you can add your new JDK here.

Always in the same window, below "Project Settings", select "Project": you have the option to select the JDK which you just added.

Comment: This answer fixed my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, IntelliJ was pointing to a JDK folder of a version I had uninstalled. For some reason the uninstaller didnt remove the Java/jdk* folder, so it was not showing any error in the configuration screen File -> Project Structure -> SDK

After finding out it was pointing to an uninstalled JDK folder then I proceeded to adjust this configuration thanks to the answer posted by UberHans

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JDK path is correct. In my case, it updated JDK version somehow but I didn't notice it, there are a lot of red underlines. After I edit JDK with the correct path, the world became green.

Answer (score 0):

1-see your version system, is window, mac or linux?

2-dowload specifc jdk(mac, window, linux).

3-Cheked your folders and file requered and path jdk/bin/(exec java)

4-see if the execut file java is compatibile your, system in your folder bin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing a Maven Reload? I had the same issue, and i tried everything, nothing worked, the only thing that worked, was reloading Maven, it fixed the problem. I hope it helps.